# Access Angular 2 app in external device while development

Tags: angular, npm

I know that by running `npm start`, you can view your app in your browser. But is there a way to view the app in an external device like a cell phone web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you just need the view, you may want to **simulate a mobile device view**.

For that, just use your browser debugger.

With Chrome press F12 and top left of debugger select : [image]

You'll then be able to select a pre-configured device :
[image]

(or just use responsive and resize as you want).

---

If you want to **really access you application from a mobile**, you'll have to be on the same network (unless you deploy your app on a remote server).

Then, if you're using Linux run `ifconfig` and spot your IP address.
On Windows run `ipconfig`.

Once You've the address of the computer where your app is running, take your mobile and access to `http://your-computer-ip:your-app-port`.

For example with a random IP and port 4200 (like you would by default with angular-cli) : http://192.168.1.64:4200

Comment: Great. Thank you. What are my options when the two are not on the same network?

Comment: @Naveed if they're not on the same network you'll need either: 1) to host it locally. For example just run your app on you computer. Then access your box admin interface and go into NAT settings. Open an external port (let say 80), and link it to your IP + port of the machine that run your app. Then go to for example : http://whatismyipaddress.com/fr/mon-ip and copy your public IP. From another device, access http://your-public-ip:your-opened-port-on-your-box and you should see your app. 2) Pay for a server online, and drop your project here. 3) If it's open source, use github gh-pages. Cheers